# How to test particular css-property value of React-element?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, emotion

I wanna check particular css-property value using enzyme. To style components - emotion css helper was used.

Let's assume next case:

```
it('title has font-size 20px', () => {
  const titleCss = css`
    font-size: 20px;
  `;

  const mountedTitle = mountWithTheme(<h1 className={titleCss}>Title</h1>);

  expect(mountedTitle).toHaveStyleRule('font-size', '20px');
});
```

Here:

- mountWithTheme - is just wrapper upon enzyme render method, but allows to pass theme;
- toHaveStyleRule is [jest-emotion](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-emotion) matcher.

That doesn't work, I got

> Property not found: font-size

If you look at jest-emotion [example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-emotion#tohavestylerule), you see that 'styled' wrapper used there, so wrapper component created, but it's not a case with 'css' helper.

I also thought about using enzyme render helper to create actual html, but it seems that cheerio wrapper doesn't have access to css values also.

Comment: not sure, but perhaps `fontSize`?

Comment: @Alex, nope, the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using enzyme, use `render` method.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'enzyme';
import Component from '.';

describe('test css', () => {
  it('test font size', () => {
    const wrapper = render(<Component />);
    expect(wrapper.find('h1')).toHaveStyleRule('font-size', '20px');
  });
});
```